# in php table tag not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want the table tag to come before the display of records in `cart()` function but it is being displayed after it rather?

How to correct that and in `cart()` function in the display of records when I am trying `<tr>` and `<td>` tags to display its not working

```
  <?php
  session_start();

   $page = 'index.php';
   $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");
if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    if(array_key_exists('cart_'.$_GET['add'], $_SESSION))
        $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+= 1;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] = 0;
    header("Location: cartindex.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['remove']))
{
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['remove']]--;
    header("Location: cartindex.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['delete']]=0;;
    header("Location: cartindex.php");
}
function cart()
{
    global $connection;
    $total = 0;
    ?>
    <table class="table table-striped"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name </th><th>Price Per Item</th><th>Cost</th><th>Add</th><th>Substract</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {

        if($value > 0)
        {
        $id = substr($key,5,strlen($key)-1);

        $result = mysqli_query($connection ,'select id,name,price from products where id ='.$id);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            $cost = $row['price'] * $value;
            echo $row['id'].'  '.$row['name'].'@'.$row['price'].'*'.$value.'='.$cost.'<a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a>'.'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a>'.'<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[delete]</a>'.'<br>';
            $total = $total + $cost;
            }
        }
    }
    ?></table><?php
    if($total==0)
    {
        ///
    }
    else
    {
        $dis="'payment made'";
        echo 'Total cost is '.$total.'<br>';
        echo '<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="alert(\'Payment accepted\');">Success</button>';
    }
}
function product()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("not connected to db ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
    $get = mysqli_query($connection , "select id,name,description,price from products where quantity > 0 order by id DESC");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get))
        {
            echo '<div    class="boxed">'.$row['name'].'<br>'.$row['price'].'<br>'.$row['description'].'<br><a href="cart.php?add='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">ADD</a>'.'<br>'.'</div>';
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try adding it as  a string. It may have something to do with output buffering

Comment: Your HTML is broken. When you're emitting the rows you're not wrapping the content in `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, so the browser will mangle the output because it doesn't know where to put them.

Comment: on line 40 i tried this :- echo '<tr><td>'$row['id'].' </td><td> '.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['price'].'</td><td>'.$value.'</td><td>'.$cost.'</td><td><a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">[+]</a></td><td>'.'<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">[-]</a></td><td>'.'<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">[delete]</a></td><td></tr>'; but i am getting the following error :- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/untitled folder/cart.php on line 40

Comment: Now you've forgotten a concatenation operator(`.`)  after the first `<tr><td>`, and perhaps elsewhere too - it's difficult to read your code posted in a comment. Post additional code as edits to your question (add it at the end - don't overwrite your original). And do some basic debugging before posting trivial error messages.

Answer (score -1):

Try replace "echo" with "return" inside functions.

Comment: `return` will immediately leave the function. The OP will get no output at all. Moral: don't guess.